# Dividing Specific Factors Within Dataframe by Number of Times in which They Appear in Dataframe (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with MLB Statcast data in RStudio and am trying to calculate swinging strike percentage (amount of swinging strikes divided by total pitches thrown by pitcher) for each individual pitcher. For the examples sake here is a sample data frame:

```
pitcher_name <- c('AJ Griffin','AJ Griffin','AJ Griffin','AJ Griffin','AJ Griffin',
                  'AJ Griffin','Adam Conley','Adam Conley','Adam Conley','Adam Conley',
                  'Adam Conley','Adam Conley')

description <- c('foul','swinging_strike','swinging_strike','swinging_strike_blocked',
                 'ball','hit_into_play','swinging_strike','swinging_strike',
                 'swinging_strike','swinging_strike_blocked','swinging_strike_blocked','ball')

pitch_analysis.data <- data.frame(pitcher_name, description)
```

The end goal is to count each pitcher's swinging strikes (both swinging strike and swinging strike blocked) and then divide this figure by the total pitches thrown by each pitcher. So for this example the final answer should be 50% (3 swinging strikes over 6 pitches) for AJ Griffin and 83% for Adam Conley (5 swinging strikes over 6 pitches). I've tried the following command using the dplyr package:

```
P <- pitch_analysis.data %>% group_by(pitcher_name, description) %>% count(description)
```

This gives me a count of each description, but I'm not sure how to use dplyr to get to the final step of grouping the two types of swinging strikes together and then dividing by the total number of pitches for each pitcher. Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Base R option would be using `aggregate`, `aggregate(description~pitcher_name, pitch_analysis.data, function(x) sum(grepl("swinging_strike", x))/length(x))`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `dplyr` and `stringr` packages, you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
P <- pitch_analysis.data %>% 
group_by(pitcher_name) %>%     
summarise(r=sum(str_detect(description,"swinging"))/n())
```

Which returns:

```
pitcher_name         r
        <fctr>     <dbl>
1  Adam Conley 0.8333333
2   AJ Griffin 0.5000000
```

We detect the word "swinging" in the description using `str_detect`, and count in how many rows it is observed using `sum`. The total number of rows per group is given by `n()`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way using only dplyr?

```
pitch_analysis.data <- data_frame(pitcher_name, description)
pitch_analysis.data %>%
mutate(simplified_description=ifelse(description=="swinging_strike_blocked",
   "swinging_strike", description)) %>%
group_by(pitcher_name, simplified_description) %>%
count(simplified_description) 

Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: pitcher_name [?]

  pitcher_name simplified_description     n
         <chr>                  <chr> <int>
1  Adam Conley                   ball     1
2  Adam Conley        swinging_strike     5
3   AJ Griffin                   ball     1
4   AJ Griffin                   foul     1
5   AJ Griffin          hit_into_play     1
6   AJ Griffin        swinging_strike     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(pitch_analysis.data)[, .(r = sum(grepl('swinging', description))/.N), pitcher_name]
#   pitcher_name         r
#1:   AJ Griffin 0.5000000
#2:  Adam Conley 0.8333333
```

---

Or with `base R` using `rowsum`

```
with(pitch_analysis.data, rowsum(+(grepl('swinging', description)), 
         pitcher_name)/tabulate(pitcher_name))
#                 [,1]
#Adam Conley 0.8333333
#AJ Griffin  0.5000000
```

or using `table/prop.table`

```
prop.table(table(pitch_analysis.data[[1]], grepl('swinging', 
            pitch_analysis.data$description)), 1)[,2]
```